# How to use an ip webcam as a webcam on my android device

Tags: webcam

What I've found on internet is how to use an android phone's camera as an ip webcam on my computer.

But I was wondering if it possible to do the opposite thing : to use an external ip webcam as a virtual internal webcam on our android devices ?

Android would recognize the external ip-camera as internal so one could use its external ip webcam as a webcam on Whatsapp for example.

I'm thinking of an application that would let me enter the ip+port of my ipwebcam and then emulate it as the internal/virtual webcam like some app do on PC

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers your question because it's not clear what you're trying to do.  But you can buy IP webcams that have software that allows you to monitor them on your Android phone, including downloading clips and taking stills from the image or clip.

Comment: You can use your android device camera and make it an ip camera and then use it on your computer (at this step the computer will recognize the ip camera as an internal camera), I want to do the opposite thing, I want to use my computer camera and make it an ip camera (still from my computer) then I want to use that ip-camera on my android device (I want my android device to recognize this ip camera as its main camera), on whatsapp for example, in fact : I just want to use an ip-camera on my android device and use it on some apps, let's say because my phone camera is broken.